# Can I produce this kind of image with my canon 550d with 50mm lens

Tags: color, image-quality, canon-550d

see this image, how splendid this is, its colors, sharpness all good. My question is can I get same result with my canon 550d with 50 mm lens or should I upgrade my camera. [image]

Comment: That's not sharp. Even at the small size that's been uploaded, the child's face is fuzzy.

Comment: Have you tried it on your current camera or increasing saturation in post? Why do you think it was the camera which did this rather than post processing and what do you expect to gain by switching camera?

Comment: If you are going to try this on your camera (and assuming your 50mm is the 50mm f/1.8), stop the lens down to f/2.8 or so - the f/1.8 is pretty soft at f/1.8, but sharpens up nicely at f/2.8.

Comment: You don't need to upgrade your camera, with your camera and lens you can produce much better images. And this kind of image you can producewith a smartphone (and I think this image WAS made with a smarthone).

Comment: Cameras don't take photos, photographers do.

Answer (score 5):

This photo looks vibrant because the photographer made it vibrant, either through a filter (smartphone) or via editing. The camera did nothing but take the photo, the same as your good camera and lens can.

The difference is the photographer. This image has good light, an obviously well planned location and props, a photographer who is engaging the child, and finally, aggressive, but somewhat pleasing post-processing. The white balance looks toward the yellow/green end, but believable, and the exposure of the scene looks good. This is a reasonably well composed shot, but the cropping bothers me as too close on the right side. The child is centered and eyes align with rule of thirds.

Unfortunately, the most impactful thing with the image wears on you after a while: the really aggressive boosted vibrance (basically saturation without impacting skin tones) and perhaps overdone whites really grab your attention, like the over boosted TVs in the TV store.

Comment: Agree with the wearing on you after a while.

Comment: Thanks for all response. I cropped this pic to upload it here as it was more than 2mb.

Comment: So what are things I should keep in mind while taking pic and post processing. It is white balance and post processed saturation?

Comment: @AlokDeo Those are easy, after the fact things. While shooting, keep in mind a) the lighting and b) what you have in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can !! In fact if you have a 50mm prime lens, you can capture even better picture than this. This picture is not that much sharp as much a 50mm prime  lens can give.
Just keep in mind to set the depth of field as you required and you always need some post-processing for making colors in the picture look vibrant ( those are simple lightroom steps ).

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted to hear. I thought that I am limited with equipments.

Comment: @cmason:" The white balance looks toward the yellow/green end" what does that means? Could you please elaborate.